# Use mintinline to textformat a glossary category using glossaries-extra

Tags: minted, glossaries-extra

I am using glossaries-extra and bib2gls. I'd like to format the text of glossary entries of certain categories using `mintinline`.
`texttt` works fine however, I would prefer to have some syntax highlighting.

For this purpose I've tried using:

```
\newmintinline{c}{}    % defines \cinline
\glssetcategoryattribute{c-code}{textformat}{cinline}
```

According to the glossaries-extra documentation (page 125, textformat), this should work, since the new `cinline` command only accepts one argument however, the output in my document when using `\gls{some-entry}` is `\@glo@text`.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}                     % Source code
\usepackage[acronym, abbreviations, record]{glossaries-extra}

\newmintinline{c}{}                     % creates \cinline
\glssetcategoryattribute{c-code}{textformat}{cinline}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{textformat}{texttt}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={test-gls.bib}]

\begin{document}
Test \gls{simple}.\\
Cinline: \cinline{void main(){ /**/ }}.\\
texttt: \gls{normal}.
\end{document}
```

test-gls.bib:

```
@entry{simple,
  name = {verysimple},
  description = {No description},
  category = {c-code}
}

@entry{normal,
  name = {texttt works},
  description = {No description},
}
```

[image: Output]

Compilation command:

```
lualatex -shell-escape test-minted.tex
bib2gls test-minted
lualatex -shell-escape test-minted.tex
```

The `.glg` file does not mention any errors. The `_minted` directory contains the following for the `simple` entry:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{err}{\PYGZbs{}@}\PYG{n}{glo}\PYG{err}{@}\PYG{n}{text} 
\end{Verbatim}
```

This looks like some glossaries-extra internal error produces that output, which is then successfully passed to minted / pygmentize. Does anyone have any insights into what could be going wrong here and how I could fix it?